# Getting error while running program at eclipse editor

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
The chromedriver version (114.0.5735.90) detected in PATH at C:\Users\User\Desktop\chromedriver.exe might not be compatible with the detected chrome version (120.0.6099.130); currently, chromedriver 120.0.6099.109 is recommended for chrome 120.*, so it is advised to delete the driver in PATH and retry
```

I tried for launching the web browser

```java
package WEBDRIVERAPI;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class WEBAPI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("Webdriver.chrome.Driver","..\\DEC2023\\Drivers\\chrome-headless-shell.exe");
        WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
        
            
    }

}
```